# ASP Hyperlinks not working in release

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, hyperlink

I have the following code in an ASP.net webforms app. The code is in C# but it's the asp aspect that I seem t be having some problems with. The links work fine in debug, but in release they don't seem to even be available as links.

```
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BackColor="#36A3E4" Width="950px">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:HyperLink ID="lnkShop" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="ShopListing.aspx?CLS=All">SHOP</asp:HyperLink></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="~/faq.aspx">FAQ's</asp:HyperLink></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="~/Feedback.aspx">FEEDBACK</asp:HyperLink></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="~/Bookmark.aspx">BOOKMARK US</asp:HyperLink></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx">ABOUT US</asp:HyperLink></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx">CONTACT US</asp:HyperLink></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Width="125px" Text="Search"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Go" /></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
```

I feel that the problem may be with iis and not the code but I can't find anything that's different from any of my other apps. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: code looks ok ...have you configured application properly in iis

Comment: I can't find anything in iis that is different fro my other apps. Although I've always developed in vb.net and only just made the switch to c#. Any ideas where I might start looking in iis?

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting an error, the links just don't register as links... It's driving me crazy... And I know it's probably going to be something easy and obvious...

Comment: Having checked the source code of the page, the hyperlinks are just displaying as below

Comment: <a id="lnkShop" style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">SHOP</a>

Comment: When released, you can't use `~` to define the root directory. Make sure you use relative paths ie `../..`. Also make sure you have ASP.NET enabled in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled upon this once and the solution to my problem was to replace the "~" with ".". For example:

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="./Contact.aspx">Test</asp:HyperLink>
```

Also, if it's not 100% required to use asp controls i would sugest using the  tag with Page.ResolveUrl() and let asp handle the page. This one is the best solution in my opinion. For example:

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Help.aspx") %>">Help</a>
```

Ps: I add this as answer because i don't have enough rep...